# Windows dd Command: Access is Denied Error

Tags: windows-10, dd, disk-image

I need to create a .dd image of one of my drive in windows, For this I chose [dd](http://www.chrysocome.net/downloads/dd-0.5.zip) utility. However it is generating aforementioned error while creating image. I have opened command line as Administrator. Below is command I am using and generated error.

```
C:\Users\hp\Downloads\dd-0.5>dd if=D: of=E:tempdisk1.dd bs=8M
rawwrite dd for windows version 0.5.
Written by John Newbigin <jn@it.swin.edu.au>
This program is covered by the GPL.  See copying.txt for details
read 95 disk NYI
Error opening input file: 5 Access is denied
```

Answer (score 0):

The references to the in and output files are wrong. In [the manual of dd](http://www.chrysocome.net//dd), it shows how to reference a partition and how to copy it:

```
dd if=\\.\d: of=e:\tempdisk1.dd bs=8M
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it says file is in use by other process, i have restarted and all but no success